# Problems with new users in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, restart

I'm a novice in MySql and can't solve problem I've bumped into (Google search gave me no results). The problem is "error 1045 access denied for user" for new users.

I'm writing a small script on PHP that will automatically create new database in MySQL and add two new users with rights only for this database. 
Here is the code :

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost", $root, $rootpass);
```

Connecting to MySQL server with superadmin rights.

```
$dbh->SetAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE new_db ;
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
            ON new_db.*
            TO new_db_admin@localhost
            IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
            GRANT SELECT 
            ON new_db.*
            TO new_db_guest@localhost
            IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
            FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
);
```

With this script I want automatically create 2 new users for "new_db". First "new_db_admin" to work with database without involving of MySQL superadmin, and second to let users of the site coonect to database. ( *IMHO that would be a good idea to give visitors rights "only to read", 'cause it will greatly reduce the possibility of SQL injection.*)

After creating new DB and adding new users I create new connection to MySQL server with   "new_db_admin" and add new tables. At this level everything works great. There are no problems with connecting to MySQL server from any user (new_db_admin, new_db_guest).

But after restarting MySQL server or restarting my PC I have "error 1045 access denied for user new_db_admin@localhost". Access to MySQL with another new user "new_db_guest" works good.

I tried to create only one user admin or guest. But after restarting MySQL server I got the same "error 1045 access denied for user new_db_admin@localhost" or if it was created only guest : "error 1045 access denied for user new_db_guest@localhost".Superadmin of MySQL server in all cases works good.

Could somebody help me to manage this troubles. I need a decision that would allow me to create new DB and new users for this DB automatically without having troubles in future.

ANY HELP WILL BE GREATLY APPRECIATED !

Here is the code I used to create users in MySQL via coomand line.

```
CREATE USER 'ADMIN'@'HOSTNAME' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin-pass';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'ADMIN'@'HOSTNAME' = PASSWORD('admin-pass');

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES 
ON 'DBNAME'.*
TO 'ADMIN'@'HOSTNAME'
IDENTIFIED BY 'admin-pass';

CREATE USER 'GUEST'@'HOSTNAME' IDENTIFIED BY 'guest-pass';
SET PASSWORD FOR 'GUEST'@'HOSTNAME' = PASSWORD('guest-pass');

GRANT SELECT
ON 'DBNAME'.*
TO 'GUEST'@'HOSTNAME'
IDENTIFIED BY 'guest-pass';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New Edit:**

Also try executing "**flush privileges**" after the grant statements.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html

---

Try splitting the Grant SQL into create user and then grant. I know you can write it the other way, but just see if it helps, even if just for debugging.

Something like:

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
GRANT ALL ON db1.* TO 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

---

Comment: I have already tried to create new user with "CREATE USER", with "CRANT ALL" and also with "INSERT INTO mysql.user" but nothing works. Anyway after restarting MySQL server I got "error 1045".

Comment: Thanks for your attention, JackDev. I tried to follow your advice with adding "FLUSH PRIVILEGES" after each new user creation but nothing changed. I still have the same trouble - new_db_admin after restarting MySQl server doesn't work (error 1045). But guest, after restarting, works normally.

Comment: Here is my code:
$dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `new_db` ;

    CREATE USER `new_db_admin`@`localhost`

    IDENTIFIED BY '12345';

    GRANT ALL ON `new_db`.* 

    TO `new_db_admin`@`localhost` 

    IDENTIFIED BY '12345'; 

    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

);
$dbh->exec( "CREATE USER `guest`@`localhost`

      IDENTIFIED BY '111';

      GRANT SELECT 

      ON `new_db`.*

      TO `guest`@`localhost` 

      IDENTIFIED BY '111';

      FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"

);

Comment: Have a look at some responses here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/access-denied.html, see if they help. And do you have multiple SQL servers running on different ports of your machine?

Comment: Yes, I did. But not in the way I was asking about. I tried different ways but all of them are working bad. The most reliable and simple way to create new users is to do it by hands. 
From one hand it's good from another - no. Good 'cause it gives you "extra points" in questions of security. Bad - 'cause it doesn't work automatically (you can't write a good script for it in php). Maybe another languages (like C+ or C#) allow you to add user with script but not php.

Comment: Anyway thanks for your last link. It really helped me. You can see the code I used to create users above.

Comment: nice! good to see you got it solved, and thanks for updating the answer. =)